# HTML div not being updated

Tags: angularjs

Not an angular expert. I'm developing a python-flask application with angularjs in the front end. I make a http call to python that returns an object. I then check if the value of a key is 'dev' or 'prd' and then use ng-show to display the corresponding divs. My problem is that the div does not update correctly every time  I click on the button to retrieve the data from python.

```
angular.forEach(response.data,function (value,key) {
    if (value == 'dev') {
    $scope.showval="True";
    //$scope.showprd="False";

    } else if (value == 'prd') {

       $scope.showprd="True";
        //$scope.showval="False";
    }
});
```

I tried $scope.$apply(), $timeout() and also tried to set the ng-show variable to false but none worked. $scope.$apply gave me an error that the digest cycle is in progress. So,i think the divs are being processed by angular. Need help to determine what's wrong. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you provide your html code, too? Thanks. Also if you're using your variables 'showval' and 'showprd' in 'ng-show' then you can assign values to those variables as follow `$scope.showval = true` and `$scope.showprd = true` and not as strings(It's only a suggestion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set you `showval` and `showprd` as `false` initially and in a certain condition your can assign it as `true` like following:

```
angular.forEach(response.data, function(value, key) {
    if (value == 'dev') {
        $scope.showval = true;
        $scope.showprd = false;

    } else if (value == 'prd') {
        $scope.showprd = true;
        $scope.showval = false;
    }
});
```

And i am supposing your html like

```
<div ng-show="showval && !showprd">Dev</div>
<div ng-show="!showval && showprd">Prod</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sudhir. I had tried that earlier but I hadn't updated the html as you mentioned. Lesson learnt 

    <div ng-show="showval && !showprd">Dev</div>
    <div ng-show="!showval && showprd">Prod</div>